# Code to partition a dual graph taking too long to run?

Tags: python, performance, graph, partitioning

I have census block population data (14,000 rows of population data) that I am trying to randomly partition into political districts. Most of the code works fine, but once I get to the "creating the initial partition" section, the code takes forever to run. I waited for an hour for the code to run, and it still did not finish. It seems strange to me that the code for partitioning the graph takes so long -- any ideas as to why and how I can fix this issue?

```
""" Here, num_dist specifies the number of districts in each plan visited in 
the short bursts. Hawaii has 51 legislative house districts. This document 
runs short bursts on the State house plan. """
num_dist = 51

# Import the relevant libraries to run short bursts: 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random 
import gerrychain
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import pickle
import zipfile


"""This is to make the code more replicable. For example, if we want the 
same result twice, we can run the code with exactly the same random seed. """
random.seed(48)


# Import attributes of gerrychain that we need to create the initial partition: 
from gerrychain import Graph, Partition, Election, proposals, updaters, constraints, accept 
from gerrychain.updaters import cut_edges, Tally
from gerrychain.tree import recursive_tree_part


# Import the Hawaii blocks graph: 
hawaii_bl = gpd.read_file('hi_merge.zip')
# Create a dual graph
hawaii_bl_dg = Graph.from_geodataframe(hi_merge, ignore_errors = True)


# Ideal population calculation: 
""" Here, the ideal population is calculated for each district. Conceptually, 
this is the total population of Hawaii divided by the number of districts. 
The total population is calculated by summing the population of all the nodes 
in the census blocks dual graph. The number of districts depends on which plan 
we are running short bursts on. The following code is for UNADJUSTED population 
data.
"""
pop = 0
for v in range(len(hawaii_bl_dg.nodes())):
    totpop = hawaii_bl_dg.nodes[v]["total"]
    pop = pop + totpop 
ideal_pop = pop/num_dist
print("Ideal Pop:", ideal_pop)


# Creating the initial partition: 
"""
Here, the initial partition is created for the short bursts. The seed plan is 
grown using Gerrychain's Partition class. Partition takes three arguments: a 
graph, an assignment of nodes to districts, and a dictionary of updaters. The 
relevant graph is the Hawaii blocks graph. The recursive_tree_part 
function is used for the assignment argument, which partitions a tree into 
range(num_dist) parts of a population that are within epsilon = 10% of the 
ideal population. Then, we extract information from each district in the 
partition through the updaters. Specifically, we extract the number of 
cut edges, whether or not it is connected, its total population and Native
Hawaiian/Pacific Islander population.)
"""

initial_partition = Partition(hawaii_bl_dg, 
assignment = recursive_tree_part(hawaii_bl_dg, range(num_dist), ideal_pop, 
  "total", 0.1, 10), 
updaters={
    "cut edges": cut_edges, 
    "connectedness": (nx.is_connected(hawaii_bl_dg)), 
    "totpop": Tally("total", alias = "totpop"), 
    "NHPIpop": Tally("other_nhpi", alias = "NHPIpop")
})
```

Comment: possibly seek a lighter solution that `gerrychain` which is uses Markov Chain Monte Carlo methods...

Comment: also the code given requires a file `hi_merge.zip`, but this file is not given or a sample of the file so the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thank you! unfortunately I don't see a space on stack overflow to upload the zip file. is there a built-in way to upload directly on this post?

Comment: the best method is to post a *small sample of the data* as a  `dict` or `list` so that others assisting you can quickly reproduce the problem...